# Create table columns in MySQL workbench from CSV

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, csv, mysql-workbench

I've searched Overflow and haven't found this answer.

I have a CSV file with 300+ columns.

I would like to upload this into MySQL workbench.

I do not want to create a table and manually enter the column names.

Is there a way to automatically create the table columns names from a CSV file?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: 'Is there a way to automatically create the table columns names from a CSV file' No but if csv file contains headers you could load to excel and transpose them

Comment: Yes the csv's first row is the column names.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.